# Los caracteres Nueva línea(LF) + Retorno de carro(CR), es decir la tecla ENTER, cómo influencia en el código html?

Tags: html, html5, codificación, ascii, li

Doy un poco de contexto:
Tengo una página html (no responsive, pero no nos centremos en eso) que pertenece a un curso que hice el año pasado. En ella, un elemento  cuyo tamaño es FIJO (width:940px; height:70px;). Dentro de él, sus elementos

tienen también tamaño fijo (width: 187px; height: 70px;).
Se produce un error:
Si en el código los items de la lista están separados por LF + CR (Enter), el navegador ubica al último elemento debajo de los demás, como si no entrara.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/*Google Font: font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap');
/* CSS Document */

body {
    font-family:'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    background-image:linear-gradient( #ffcfa2fb,#4c3d2efb);
    margin: 0px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    }

#contenedor {
    width:960px;
    height:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;

    
    }

header {
    height:290px;
    }

h1 {
    margin:0 0 0 40px;
    color:#020103;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size:3rem;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 8px #e66e0b8d;
    }

a {
    color:#4b9be1;
    text-decoration:none;
    }
#botonera_principal {
    width:940px;
    height:70px;
    border-left: 20px solid black;
    background-color:#050505;
    }

    #botonera_principal:hover{
    border-left: 20px solid #fe8d0c;
    }

#botonera_principal ul {
    width:940px;
    height:70px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;}

#botonera_principal ul li {
    display: inline;
    width: 187px;
    height: 70px;
}

#botonera_principal ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color:#f8f8f8;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align: center;
    border-right:1px dotted #ffffff;
    width: 187px;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    
    }
    
#botonera_principal ul li a:hover {
    background-color:#e8be64;
    }
    
#marca {
    background-image:url(imagenes/fondo_marca.jpg);
    height:200px;
    padding-top:27px;
    border-left:solid 20px black;

    }
    #marca:hover{
    border-left:solid 20px #d23e0d;

    }
#contenido {
    padding:20px;
    background-color:#ffffff70;
    border-left: 20px solid black;
    }
#contenido:hover{
border-left: 20px solid #b5fcfb;    
}

#ejer_1, #ejer_2, #ejer_3, #ejer_4 {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 2%;
}
#ejer_1 {
    background-color: #ffffcc;
}
#ejer_2 {
    background-color: #e6ffcc;
}
#ejer_3 {
    background-color: #ccf2ff;
}
#ejer_4 {
    background-color: #ffccff;
}

.ajustar {
    width: 100%;
}

h2 {
    color:#0a0707;}

footer {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    padding:20px;
    border-left: 20px solid black;
    }
footer:hover{
    border-left: 20px solid #fcf94bfb;
}

footer a {
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:bold;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Diseño y Programación WEB</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>
<section id="contenedor">
    <header>
        <nav id="botonera_principal">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="catalogo.php">Catálogo</a></li>
                <li><a href="noticias.php">Noticias</a></li>
                <li><a href="clientes.php">Clientes</a></li>
                <li><a href="contacto.php">Contáctenos</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="marca">
            <h1>Diseño y Programación WEB II<br/>IFEE</h1>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section id="contenido">
    <h2>Introducción a PHP</h2>
    <div id="ejer_1">
        <h4>
            <?php
            echo "Qué es y para qué sirve PHP?"."<br/>";
            ?>
        </h4>

        <p>
            <?php
            echo "PHP es un lenguaje de programación de código abierto del lado del servidor que se utiliza principalmente para crear páginas web dinámicas."."<br/>";
            ?>
        </p>
        <p>
            <?php
             echo "La abreviatura nació originariamente de “Personal Home Page Tools”, aunque hoy en día se ha convertido en el acrónimo recursivo para “PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor”."."<br/>";
            ?>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="ejer_2">
        <?php
        echo "TRABAJO FINAL"."<br/>";
        echo "INTEGRADOR"."<br/>";
        echo "PHP Y MySQL"."<br/>";
        ?>

    </div>
    <div id="ejer_3">
        <?php
         $varint=76; $varstr="Esto es un dato tipo \"String\" "; $varbool=TRUE;

         echo 'Los siguientes son los valores de las variables de nombre $varint, $varstr y $varbool:'."<br/><br/>";

         print $varint."<br/>".$varstr."<br/>".$varbool;
        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="ejer_4">
        <?php
        $primint=45;
        $segint=7;
        $terint=3;
        //operación matemática:
        $oper=$primint*$segint/$terint;

        print $primint."<br/>";
        print $segint."<br/>";
        print $terint."<br/>";

        echo "$primint * $segint / $terint=$oper";
        ?>
    </div>
    </section>

<footer>
<p>Profesora: CH</p></footer>
</footer>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

**Pero si en el código todos los items están escritos uno junto al otro, el navegador muestra la barra de navegación como fue pensada(todos los items entran en ella)**

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/*Google Font: font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap');
/* CSS Document */

body {
    font-family:'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    background-image:linear-gradient( #ffcfa2fb,#4c3d2efb);
    margin: 0px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    }

#contenedor {
    width:960px;
    height:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;

    
    }

header {
    height:290px;
    }

h1 {
    margin:0 0 0 40px;
    color:#020103;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size:3rem;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 8px #e66e0b8d;
    }

a {
    color:#4b9be1;
    text-decoration:none;
    }
#botonera_principal {
    width:940px;
    height:70px;
    border-left: 20px solid black;
    background-color:#050505;
    }

    #botonera_principal:hover{
    border-left: 20px solid #fe8d0c;
    }

#botonera_principal ul {
    width:940px;
    height:70px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;}

#botonera_principal ul li {
    display: inline;
    width: 187px;
    height: 70px;
}

#botonera_principal ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color:#f8f8f8;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align: center;
    border-right:1px dotted #ffffff;
    width: 187px;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    
    }
    
#botonera_principal ul li a:hover {
    background-color:#e8be64;
    }
    
#marca {
    background-image:url(imagenes/fondo_marca.jpg);
    height:200px;
    padding-top:27px;
    border-left:solid 20px black;

    }
    #marca:hover{
    border-left:solid 20px #d23e0d;

    }
#contenido {
    padding:20px;
    background-color:#ffffff70;
    border-left: 20px solid black;
    }
#contenido:hover{
border-left: 20px solid #b5fcfb;    
}

#ejer_1, #ejer_2, #ejer_3, #ejer_4 {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 2%;
}
#ejer_1 {
    background-color: #ffffcc;
}
#ejer_2 {
    background-color: #e6ffcc;
}
#ejer_3 {
    background-color: #ccf2ff;
}
#ejer_4 {
    background-color: #ffccff;
}

.ajustar {
    width: 100%;
}

h2 {
    color:#0a0707;}

footer {
    background-color:#ffffff;
    padding:20px;
    border-left: 20px solid black;
    }
footer:hover{
    border-left: 20px solid #fcf94bfb;
}

footer a {
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:bold;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Diseño y Programación WEB</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>
<section id="contenedor">
    <header>
        <nav id="botonera_principal">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li><li><a href="catalogo.php">Catálogo</a></li><li><a href="noticias.php">Noticias</a></li><li><a href="clientes.php">Clientes</a></li><li><a href="contacto.php">Contáctenos</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="marca">
            <h1>Diseño y Programación WEB II<br/>IFEE</h1>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section id="contenido">
    <h2>Introducción a PHP</h2>
    <div id="ejer_1">
        <h4>
            <?php
            echo "Qué es y para qué sirve PHP?"."<br/>";
            ?>
        </h4>

        <p>
            <?php
            echo "PHP es un lenguaje de programación de código abierto del lado del servidor que se utiliza principalmente para crear páginas web dinámicas."."<br/>";
            ?>
        </p>
        <p>
            <?php
             echo "La abreviatura nació originariamente de “Personal Home Page Tools”, aunque hoy en día se ha convertido en el acrónimo recursivo para “PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor”."."<br/>";
            ?>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="ejer_2">
        <?php
        echo "TRABAJO FINAL"."<br/>";
        echo "INTEGRADOR"."<br/>";
        echo "PHP Y MySQL"."<br/>";
        ?>

    </div>
    <div id="ejer_3">
        <?php
         $varint=76; $varstr="Esto es un dato tipo \"String\" "; $varbool=TRUE;

         echo 'Los siguientes son los valores de las variables de nombre $varint, $varstr y $varbool:'."<br/><br/>";

         print $varint."<br/>".$varstr."<br/>".$varbool;
        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="ejer_4">
        <?php
        $primint=45;
        $segint=7;
        $terint=3;
        //operación matemática:
        $oper=$primint*$segint/$terint;

        print $primint."<br/>";
        print $segint."<br/>";
        print $terint."<br/>";

        echo "$primint * $segint / $terint=$oper";
        ?>
    </div>
    </section>

<footer>
<p>Profesora: CH</p></footer>
</footer>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

**Hay muchas cosas que no entiendo todavía, pero sería correcto decir que los caracteres CR+FL (Enter) tienen un tamaño en pixeles?
Hay otra razón por la que se produce esto?
Gracias por tomarse el tiempo de leer.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

después del **contactenos** , prueba con el tag

```
<br/>
```

, este funciona como el enter

sino en el siguiente tag dentro del class, agrega "sm-3", también te puede ayudar

ambos te sirven para hacer separación de párrafos

saludos